# Distinct on id with ordering by possible duplicate names

Tags: sql, postgresql, distinct

I have the following requisites for a query:

- Needs to ordered on a inner joined table (see `from_products_products` below),
- Allow duplicates names on `from_products_products`
- It cannot return duplicates records on the origin table (distinct on `products.id`).

The following query will eliminate the duplicate names, which is not desired, as I had to put a distinct on `from_products_products.name` because of the use in `order by`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (from_products_products.name, products.id) "products".* FROM "products" 
  INNER JOIN "suppliers_plugin_source_products" ON "suppliers_plugin_source_products"."to_product_id" = "products"."id"
  INNER JOIN "products" "from_products_products" ON "from_products_products"."id" = "suppliers_plugin_source_products"."from_product_id"
  INNER JOIN "suppliers_plugin_source_products" "sources_from_products_products_join" ON "sources_from_products_products_join"."to_product_id" = "products"."id"
  INNER JOIN "suppliers_plugin_suppliers" ON "suppliers_plugin_suppliers"."id" = "sources_from_products_products_join"."supplier_id"
  WHERE "products"."profile_id" = 45781 AND (("products"."type" IN ('SuppliersPlugin::DistributedProduct') OR "products"."type" IS NULL)) AND (products.archived <> true)
  ORDER BY from_products_products.name ASC, products.id
```

Using `GROUP BY` has the same effect and also don't remove duplicates;

The original query that gives duplicate `products` when the `INNER JOIN` doesn't match any product:

```
SELECT "products".* FROM "products" 
  INNER JOIN "suppliers_plugin_source_products" ON "suppliers_plugin_source_products"."to_product_id" = "products"."id"
  INNER JOIN "products" "from_products_products" ON "from_products_products"."id" = "suppliers_plugin_source_products"."from_product_id"
  INNER JOIN "suppliers_plugin_source_products" "sources_from_products_products_join" ON "sources_from_products_products_join"."to_product_id" = "products"."id"
  INNER JOIN "suppliers_plugin_suppliers" ON "suppliers_plugin_suppliers"."id" = "sources_from_products_products_join"."supplier_id"
  WHERE "products"."profile_id" = 45781 AND (("products"."type" IN ('SuppliersPlugin::DistributedProduct') OR "products"."type" IS NULL)) AND (products.archived <> true)
  ORDER BY from_products_products.name ASC
```

So, how to overcome this on PostgreSQL?

PS: This is part of open-source software Noosfero-ecosol

Comment: I don't understand your question.  Can you give examples of the data being produced and what you actually want?  Do you want duplicates or not?

Comment: Gordon, I have refactored the requisites, please take a look now

Comment: The query makes little sense: if you only want columns from "products" why do you join all the other tables (the same could be done by a simple EXISTS(), avoiding all the "duplicates") ? And why do you join "suppliers_plugin_source_products" *twice* (with exactly the same conditions) The `order by from_products_products.name` looks awkward, too.

Comment: the last two inner joins is necessary as I sometimes filter by `suppliers_plugin_suppliers.id`

Comment: There is no *sometimes* . we can only react on the code that you show, not on the code that you don't show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this do what you want?

```
with t as (
    SELECT DISTINCT ON (products.id) "products".*,
           from_products_products.name as from_products_name
    FROM "products" 
      INNER JOIN "suppliers_plugin_source_products" ON "suppliers_plugin_source_products"."to_product_id" = "products"."id"
      INNER JOIN "products" "from_products_products" ON "from_products_products"."id" = "suppliers_plugin_source_products"."from_product_id"
      INNER JOIN "suppliers_plugin_source_products" "sources_from_products_products_join" ON "sources_from_products_products_join"."to_product_id" = "products"."id"
      INNER JOIN "suppliers_plugin_suppliers" ON "suppliers_plugin_suppliers"."id" = "sources_from_products_products_join"."supplier_id"
      WHERE "products"."profile_id" = 45781 AND (("products"."type" IN ('SuppliersPlugin::DistributedProduct') OR "products"."type" IS NULL)) AND (products.archived <> true)
      ORDER BY products.id
     )
select t.*
from t
order by from_products_name
```

It seems to meet your requirements.

EDIT:

If the above does what you want, I can think of five options:

- The above using a CTE.
- Basically the same logic, using a subquery.
- Using window functions, which is structurally very similar.
- Using `group by`.
- Using a `where` clause for the filtering logic.

Here is the `group by` method:

```
    SELECT "products".*,
           MIN(from_products_products.name) as from_products_name
    FROM "products" 
      INNER JOIN "suppliers_plugin_source_products" ON "suppliers_plugin_source_products"."to_product_id" = "products"."id"
      INNER JOIN "products" "from_products_products" ON "from_products_products"."id" = "suppliers_plugin_source_products"."from_product_id"
      INNER JOIN "suppliers_plugin_source_products" "sources_from_products_products_join" ON "sources_from_products_products_join"."to_product_id" = "products"."id"
      INNER JOIN "suppliers_plugin_suppliers" ON "suppliers_plugin_suppliers"."id" = "sources_from_products_products_join"."supplier_id"
      WHERE "products"."profile_id" = 45781 AND (("products"."type" IN ('SuppliersPlugin::DistributedProduct') OR "products"."type" IS NULL)) AND (products.archived <> true)
      GROUP BY products.id
      ORDER BY from_products_name;
```

This form depends on `products.id` being declared as a primary key.  Alternatively, you can put all the columns from that table in the `group by`.

Comment: Neat query and how boring postgresql can be! The problem now is that I'm  using Rails, so writing custom queries is not a good option :(

Comment: Gordon, do you imagine another way to acomplish this or do you think this is the only solution?

Comment: This last query was easy to use with Rails

Answer (score 1):

Rewriting (simplifying the aliases) yields:

```
SELECT p1.*
FROM products p1
INNER JOIN suppliers_plugin_source_products spsp
        ON spsp.to_product_id = p1.id
INNER JOIN products p2
        ON p2.id = spsp.from_product_id
INNER JOIN suppliers_plugin_source_products spsp2
        ON spsp2.to_product_id = p1.id -- <<-- Huh?
INNER JOIN suppliers_plugin_suppliers sps
        ON sps.id = spsp2.supplier_id
WHERE p1.profile_id = 45781
  AND (p1."type" IN ('SuppliersPlugin::DistributedProduct') OR p1."type" IS NULL)
  AND p1.archived <> true
ORDER BY p2.name ASC -- <<-- Huh?
    ;
```

The outer query only refers to the product tables p1 and p2.
Assuming that JOINing the "suppliers_plugin_source_products" table **twice** was unintentional, this can be reduced to:

```
SELECT p1.*
FROM products p1
JOIN products p2
  ON EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM suppliers_plugin_source_products spsp
    -- the next line might not be necessary ...
    INNER JOIN suppliers_plugin_suppliers sps ON sps.id = spsp.supplier_id
    WHERE spsp.to_product_id = p1.id
    AND spsp.from_product_id = p2.id
    )
WHERE p1.profile_id = 45781 
  AND (p1."type" IN ('SuppliersPlugin::DistributedProduct') OR p1."type" IS NULL)
  AND p1.archived <> true
ORDER BY p2.name ASC
    ;
```

Comment: Interesting approach, but this doesn't fit on Rails. Besides, isn't it slower?

Comment: It cannot be slower. It is possibly even more correct. And I don't care about Rails.

Comment: This is the only approach to do an "unique" inner join? Maybe there should exist a simple modifier to `INNER JOIN`?

Comment: It is a (IMHO the simplest) way to express that you only want  `p1 JOIN  p2` , having a JOIN (theta) relation which can be deduced by the presense of records in a few  related tables. And INNER is a noise word.